# VBA macro to convert cell Function into text expression is very slow

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set `'` in front of every formula so that the function is not evaluated and is displayed as plain text.

```
Sub ConvertFormulasToTextForSheet()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim sheetName As String
 
  sheetName = "Sheet1" 

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)

  Set rng = ws.UsedRange

  For Each cell In rng
      cell.Value = "'" & cell.Formula

  Next cell

End Sub
```

executing that function is extremly slow, it basically convert 3-4 per seconds.
Is there any way how to speed that up?

Comment: Maybe `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Replace "=", "'="`  Will only work if there's only one = in each formula.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is relavant but there is an option to "Show Formulas" on the formula tab.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, thanks that worked very good. The function finished within seconds over a large range.

Comment: @TinMan thanks, I am aware of that, unfortunately things are complicated...

Answer (score 3):

Use an array:

```
Dim vals As Variant
vals = ws.UsedRange.Formula

If IsArray(vals) Then
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(vals, 1) to UBound(vals, 1)
        For j = LBound(vals, 2) to UBound(vals, 2)
            vals(i, j) = "'" & vals(i, j)
        Next
    Next
Else
    vals = "'" & vals
End If

ws.UsedRange.Value = vals
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are much more efficient that iterating over each formula.  Setting  `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` will also give the code a performance boost.
I added `Suspend` as a parameter.  This will make it easy to enable and disable the formulas.

**Usage**:

> ```
> SuspendFormula ActiveSheet, True
> SuspendFormula ActiveSheet, False
> ```

**Code**:

```
Sub SuspendFormula(Worksheet As Worksheet, Suspend As Boolean)
    Dim InitialCalculationState As XlCalculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    InitialCalculationState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = Worksheet.UsedRange
    Dim Data As Variant
        
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = Target.Formula
    Else
        Data = Target.Formula
    End If
        
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
        
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data)
        For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            If Suspend Then
                If Left(Data(r, c), 1) = "=" Then Data(r, c) = "'" & Data(r, c)
            Else
                If Left(Data(r, c), 2) = "'=" Then Data(r, c) = Mid(Data(r, c), 2)
            End If
        Next
    Next
        
    Target.Formula = Data
    
    Application.Calculation = InitialCalculationState
End Sub
```